# Superslides, some slide remain blank using chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using [this](http://nicinabox.com/superslides) and I've got a strange problem I cannot reproduce on the demo, using chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m.

The slides 4 and 5 remain somewhat hidden.

Can be seen at [link](http://dev1.juganville.com/en/bed-and-breakfeast-in-16-century-manor-in-normandy-rooms-la-tour-spacious-and-bright-room-exposed-ceiling-beams#3)

If I remove the property `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`from img item then it seems to solve the problem.

I'm using bootstrap 3.1 and jquery 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old question but i just experienced the same problem in Google Chrome v.39 (tested on Mac OS 10.10 and Kubuntu) using [jquery.superslides](http://nicinabox.com/superslides/) v0.6.2.

I had, while sliding through the page, using the "next" and "prev" buttons blank pages now and then. I triple checked all my CSS and DOM. Removing

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

did not do the trick for me, but i finally found the reason:

The plugins "hashchange" function causes the behavior. If you set it to false, the bug is gone.

Until now i haven't got any other solution for realising the change of the hash-tag while sliding.. but hopefully its useful for anyone to know what causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and replaced `jquery.superslides` from the one I downloaded from [SuperSlides](http://archive.nicinabox.com/superslides) and it got resolved.